# Block repetitive IP addresses with specific URL parameter

Tags: wordpress, ip, ip-address, block, google-ads-api

I am running google ads and having invalid click issues my ad serve only in Dubai, problem i face my competitor click bomb my ad from UK, FRACE and other countries mostly from Europe and Britain, I excluded all the world expect Dubai but my competitor still able to see my ad and clicking them with some kind of bot till Dawn to Dusk.

I talked with google and they said our system filter invalid clicks but still 30 to 50 percent clicks google consider legit.

[image: 1]

I come up with a solution by installing a plugin in WordPress and filtering traffic by filtering URL with "/?gclid=" parameter. But now I have to do it manually.

My question is there any automate rule in WordPress so I can block an IP address automatically if he click on my ad more then a couple of times.

Comment: Have you asked your hosting service for help with this? They may be able to install some sort of geographic blocking between your web server and the public net.  As you have discovered, this problem is hard to solve reliably from within a web site.

Comment: i did but unfortunately they were unable to provide a solution.....

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you consider this more a google ads problem than a webmaster problem? Your take to approach google is the best one imo.
Google ads should not count a person twice if the click on the same add twice in a row within a certain time period (from the same ip address) and this should be your argument with google. This logic is simple enough so that google ads should have it in order to ensure fair business even from google's perspective.

If you succeed with this, your competitor will think he is successful while doing you no harm.

Trying to block those ip addresses can again be bypassed by your competitor with the next version of his clickbomb trick.

Comment: This is a big problem with google ads they said they count not more then 2 clicks per IP but that's not true, also there exclude IP option is kind of crappy. That's why there are so many click fraud blocking companies with high paid plans.